# In LEGO Star Wars: The Force Awakens (mobile version ios android 3ds), Oscillator Bombing Run, how do you get the minikits?

Tags: android, lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

I got one, by blowing up the gold object in the trench, and I can see that the collectable detector shows an arrow in the middle of space in the opening scene where you are shooting tie fighters, but I can't for the life of me find that second minikit.

Answer (score 1):

The gold object is one.

The other, I couldn't find for the longest time. I just got it tonight. It is something I shot (don't know what) in the section before the red/blue/yellow panels, but after Poe's Xwing dives in. Good luck.